# Divided difference acts on what space?

Tags: functions, interpolation

I'm currently trying to explain divided differences with a view to defining the Newton form of the interpolating polynomial. I'm using the definition:

The *$k$th divided difference* of a function $f$ at the sites $t_{i}, ..., t_{i+k}$ to be the leading coefficient (i.e. the coefficient of $x^{k}$) of the $k+1$st order polynomial that agrees with $f$ at $\textbf{t}=(t_{i}, ... ,t_{i+k})$. We denote it by
$$[t_{i}, ..., t_{i+k}]f.$$

And I wanted to mention that it is linear in $f$. I was hoping to say something along the lines of:

The function $[t_{i}, ..., t_{i+k}]f: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is linear in $f$ in that if $f = \lambda g + \mu h$ then $$[t_{i}, ..., t_{i+k}]f=\lambda [t_{i}, ..., t_{i+k}]g + \mu [t_{i}, ..., t_{i+k}]h.$$

But I realized that I'm not exactly sure what the space $V$ actually is. Is it the space of all real-valued functions?

Comment: How about continuous functions (on the whole real line or on a compact subinterval)?

Comment: Do the functions have to be continuous though? Also, do I need to include the fact that the $t_{i},...t_{i+k}$ are sort of part of the input? I assume it's probably okay to just assume they're fixed.

Comment: No, you can also choose all real-valued functions. I do not understand what you mean with "input".

Comment: Sorry, I edited. Presumably it's okay to assume the sites are fixed?

Comment: Yes, you only vary $f$.